# Life time of temporaries passed to functions

Tags: c++

is below code a valid - non UB?

```
struct GeoPoint {
  std::string toString() const {
      return std::string("123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890");
  }
};

struct Data {
  const GeoPoint  getPt() const {
      return GeoPoint();
  }
};

void foo(const char* c) {
    std::cout << c << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    Data dr;
    foo(dr.getPt().toString().c_str());    
}
```

My understanding is that temporaries created during function argument evaluation are destroyed until the end of full expression - so the function executes, then ends and then temps. are destroyed. Am I right? I am getting crashes in similar code, but the function actually takes a variable number of arguments throught a variable number of arguments macro. So the code looks more like this:

```
void log_print(char const * szFormat, ...) { ... }
#define LOG(fmt, ...) do { \
    log_print(fmt, ##__VA_ARGS__);\
} while(0)

Data dr;
LOG("%s", dr.getPt().toString().c_str());
```

Comment: Does this code crash?  If it doesn't we really can't help you with what is going on except to confirm that yes, the temporaries exist until at least the function returns.

Comment: I am not experiencing any problems running the code you posted. It looks well defined to me.

Comment: Yes, it works for me too - no crashes, I should have posted link to coliru: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c52de7faf294ab05

Comment: But I see a crash in debugger of my app (much larger codebase) exactly in such place :-) must be some other bug

Comment: @mike links to code are frowned upon here because people behind proxies can't seem them; they go stale / change don't turn up in searches etc etc.  This is why the minimal verifiable example is required

Comment: @UKMonkey I tried with coliru (link above) but no luck

Comment: @mike Make sure whatever object you use to start the function chain is valid.  You could be calling functions on a bad object which can/will cause problems.  Trying to break it down into a [mcve] will also help.  Keep removing code until the least amount you can possibly have the reproduces the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code is well-defined.

The pointer returned back by `c_str()` is valid for the lifetime of the call to `foo`: the anonymous temporary does not go out of scope until the end of the statement `foo(dr.getPt().toString().c_str());`.